# Efficient way to update instances with random values

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django with PostgreSQL and I want to know if there is a way to update a certain number of models, that have uniques fields, with random values.

My problem is I need to update 5k of users changing his emails and usernames with random values. These fields are uniques, which means two instances can't have the same values. My logic is: for each user, (1) generate random email string, then if there isn't any user with that email, use that string, else back to **1**

```py
# Python2.7 Django 1.11, but everything helps
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string

for user in User.objects.order_by('-pk')[:5000].iterator():

    # Generate random email
    while True:
        random_email = get_random_string(10)
        if not User.objects.filter(email=random_email).exists():
            user.email = random_email
            break

    # Generate random username
    while True:
        random_username = get_random_string(10)
        if not User.objects.filter(username=random_username).exists():
            user.username = random_username
            break

    user.save()
```

Comment: and? What is the problem?

Comment: If this is a one time job, go ahead and do it without a check. You are quite unlikely to hit any same string for length 10.

Comment: @MohitC I need to prevent collisions and I want to optimize the DB hits. Then, I want to know if there is a better way to do this hitting the DB fewer times than the actually I do. I hit, at minimum, 3 times for each loop. 5k of users it's equivalent to 15k of connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your implementation is efficient enough. Now, if you are worried about hitting DB too much, maybe you can remove the `filter().exists()` and generate the unique string list beforehand. Like this:

```
unique_strings = list(set([get_random_string(10) for x in range(15000)]))  # or use User.objects.all().count()

for x in range(15000 - len(unique_strings)):
   # I tested with 500,000 values, did not get any duplicates so it is highly unlikely to get in this block
   new_str = get_random_string(10)
   if not new_str in unique_strings:
        unique_strings.append(new_str)

for (unique_str, user) in zip(unique_strings, User.objects.all().iterator()):
    user.username = unique_str
    user.email = unique_str
    user.save()
```

Then DB hit will be reduced from 3 times to once.

Comment: The answer is fine, it's does fewer DB hits than the original solution, but it was not what I was looking for. Anyway, I chose it because no other answer appeared.
The problem of what you are doing is that I can have a database with 5 million users and I only want to do this to 250 users (the number 5k is really a variable), so this solution takes me more time and RAM than the original solution.
In this latter case, the chances of collisions are low yeah, but not non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more efficient using [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) (added in Django 2.2). Roughly, you put all your pre-modified objects in a list, then modify the instances, and then call `bulk_update` at once:

```
users = User.objects.all()

# Get a random string per user + 100 to cover (unlikely) collisions
# set() removes duplicates
random_emails = set(
    [get_random_string(10)
     for _ in range(users.count() + 100)])

# Here you could check if you have at least
# as many random_emails as users:
# assert len(random_emails) >= users.count()

for user, email in zip(users, random_emails):
    user.email = email

User.objects.bulk_update(users, ["email"])
```

Be sure to read the Django docs about `bulk_update`, because it has some limitations like not emiting signals, not calling the `save()` method, and more.

Comment: Yeah but, what if the random email already exists?

Comment: Get all emails from the DB, turn them into a set, and use set operations to remove random emails that already exist.